# Dealing with speech marks with string.match

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have an xml page that I have a monitoring system scanning, here is the source data:

```
`<queues>
<queue name="workQueue">
<stats size="0" consumerCount="28" enqueueCount="29320" dequeueCount="37000"/>
```

And here is the code I have so far:

```
local pattern = " size=(%d+) "

local a = alarm.get("CO13974960-19518")

local vsize = string.match(a.message, pattern)

local sum = vsize
```

I'm trying to target this bit of data from the XML page:

```
stats size="0"
```

The value "0" is the number I am interested in, and I'm looking for a way to capture that figure (no matter what it reaches) via the script.

I think my script is looking for:

`size=0` rather than `size="0"`

But I'm unsure on the correct syntax on how to do this.

Comment: Use escaped quotes inside string literals: `local pattern = " size=\"(%d+)\" "`

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it's not a good idea to use Lua pattern (or regex) to parse XML, use a XML parser instead.

---

Anyway, in this example,

```
local pattern = " size=(%d+) "
```

- Whitespace matters, so the white space in the beginning and end are
  trying to match white space character but failed.
- You have already noticed that you need double quotes around `(%d)`, they have to be escaped in double quoted strings.
- `+` is greedy, it might work here, but the non-greedy `-` is a better
  choice.

This works

```
local pattern = "size=\"(%d-)\""
```

Note you could use single quotes strings so that you don't need escape double quotes:

```
local pattern = 'size="(%d-)"'
```